# How to remove default upload field label?

Tags: html, symfony, twig

In one of my uploader field, I see a caption displays as the field label which I have failed to change or remove.

Seriously I don't know where it comes from

[image]
How to disappear that default label? What to change in my html code? Actually i am using twig php to call the field from an Class object.

**profile.html.twig**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h4>{{user.civilite}} {{ user.nom }} {{ user.prenom }}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" id="profile-image" src="{{ asset('uploads/profile/images') }}/{{ user.imageprofil }}" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**ProfileFormType.php**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('imageProfil')->add('imageFile', VichImageType::class, array('label' => false, 'required' => false ))

                ->add('civilite', ChoiceType::class, array('choices' => array('M.' => 'M', 'Mme.' => 'Mme'),
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'placeholder' => 'Nom de Famille',
                        'style' => "margin-bottom:5px;"
            )))
                ->add('nom', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Nom de Famille', 'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'placeholder' => 'Nom de Famille',
                        'style' => "margin-bottom:5px;"
            )))
                ->add('prenom', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Prénom', 'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'placeholder' => 'Prénom',
                        'style' => "margin-bottom:5px;"
            )))
                ->add('email', EmailType::class, array('label' => 'Email', 'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'placeholder' => 'Email',
                        'style' => "margin-bottom:5px;"
            )))
```

Where i can code to disappear the label caption?

i.e.  **"Aucun fichier choisi"**

**Solution**

```
<style>
   #app_user_profile_imageFile_file {
         display: block;
         color: transparent;
   }

   #app_user_profile_imageProfil{
         width: 100px;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: To render the form you can use form helper functions: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/rendering.html . Or if it doesn't help you can try form themes to fully customize form rendering: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/form_themes.html

Answer (score 0):

This is native part of webkit browsers.

You can't remove it the normal way, but you can trick the browser not to show it with little bit of css - just make the font color transparent.

```
input[type='file'] {
  color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: You can check my answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add option parameter `['label' => false]`